# swift 2 - current location stuck on simulated location

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am trying to test my app on my iPod through the wireless.  in the simulator I simulated location to Hawaii, now on the iPod it always says the location is Hawaii.  I tried disconnecting and restarting the app and even tried to "not simulate" but it doesn't update to my real location based on the wi-fi.

how can i use the real location of my iPod?

solved

had to restart the device as mentioned in comments

Comment: you need to restart the device. this has been an issue for years

Comment: perfect that did it!